# Lightweight Modern Distro for Atom Machine?

Tags: intel, distribution-choice, atom

With all the distros out there, I'm not up to date on which does what.  I have an old `Atom D2500` box that I want to get going.  It's currently running `CentOS8` but that lineage is terminated.  So I've been researching options and tried `Puppy OS`, which can't even install from the ISO image.  Oh well.

Anybody have any recommendations?  I'm looking for small, lightweight, where I can install modern `Ruby`, `gems`, etc.

Any insight appreciated.  Cheers.

Comment: RHEL 8 has been free for private use for months now. Upgrading to it is trivial. Also, there are multiple RHEL8 clones, e.g. AlmaLinux.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Upgrading isn't the issue.  It's a dormant box.  Want to move to something I can get lightweight and affording modern `packages` and `gems`, including `Ruby 3.x`.  No GUI, just basic footprint plus my chosen packages.  I'm not versed in these `distros` for things like `Atom` boxes.  `Alma` looks promising, much along the lines of `CentOS8`.  Cheers

Comment: If you are looking for a lightweight distro, try Alpine or KISS Linux. "Lightweight" is not for beginners though - it requires knowledge of command line and advanced knowledge of (GNU/)Linux.

Comment: +1 for `Alpine` linux.

Comment: Alpine it is.  Cheers